# Windows 10 “Display Settings” Rearrange your displays" configuration does not persist

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have a laptop with 3 monitors, and the 3 monitors are configured to extend the desktop. I am able to configure them in the arrangement I want, and then successfully apply the configuration, but every time the display turns off, or sleeps, or hibernates, the arrangement reverts back to a (clumsy) default. In addition, the windows that were open are moved back to my primary display, the laptop screen.

How can I troubleshoot this, and or force my custom arrangement to persist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause is in this case but as a general rule, if you're seeing issues with displays, wiping out your display drivers and reinstalling might be worth a try.

You could use DDU to uninstall everything and then reboot to see if that helps.

Comment: I've been using the GeForce Experience app, and I have tried wiping the existing via a "fresh install", but no luck.  What is "DDU"?

Comment: Display Driver Uninstaller. Commonly-used tool to clear any and all display drivers that might be in conflict or not working as desired.